# clientContext.Site vs clientContext.Web difference

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

What is the difference between `clientContext.Site` and `clientContext.Web` when using the Client Object Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`site`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553781%28v=office.14%29.aspx) returns an SP.Site object (called "Site Collection" in non-API documentation) and [`web`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee550397%28v=office.14%29.aspx) returns an SP.Web object (called "Site" in non-API documentation). The `web`'s Site is the same as `site`.

Different operations can be performed upon the different hierarchical objects. Either the Site or the Web will be required depending upon operation (the operations are exposed by the API)  - that's all.

See [Overview of Sites (aka "SP.Web") and Site Collections (aka "SP.Site") in SharePoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262410.aspx) - for how the two different types relate.